# How values from SPListItem before and after Event?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, events

I have an Event Receiver that will fire when a SPListItem in a SPList is updated. I'm using the ItemUpdated() Event.

I want to get the values from before the event so I can compare which fields that have been edited.

How do I do that?

```
if (properties.ListTitle == "Lista")
            {
                if (properties.AfterProperties["Start Time"].ToString() != properties.ListItem["Start Time"].ToString())
                {
                    string s = "hej";
                }
            }

            try
            {
                // ID for the site from the properties object
                Guid siteId = properties.SiteId;
                // ID for the list from the properties object
                Guid listId = properties.ListId;
                // ID for the list item from the properties object
                int listItemId = properties.ListItemId;

                SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
                          {
                           // Code stuff
                          });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
     if (properties.ListTitle == "ListName")
    {
         //AfterProperties gives new value and ListItem gives the previously stored
         if(properties.AfterProperties["ColumnName"].ToString()!=properties.ListItem["ColumnName"].ToString())
         //Your code Here
    }
```

Comment: I tried that, but I get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: What is the thing that you tried?can you update your code in the question?

Comment: Try `["Start_x0020_Time"]` instead of '["Start Time"]'. Check the internal name of your column it will be Start_x0020_Time. I am assuming you are getting null reference here:
`if (properties.AfterProperties["Start Time"].ToString() != properties.ListItem["Start Time"].ToString())`

Comment: Please debug and trace out the line where you getting Object Reference not set

Comment: So if this helped you,it shud be marked as answer. Please do the needful

Comment: For ItemUpdated, `properties.AfterProperties["ColumnName"].ToString() != properties.ListItem["ColumnName"].ToString()` will always be false.

Answer (score 2):

If the list is a Document Library, you can use [BeforeProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventproperties.beforeproperties.aspx). If not, the only way to get the values from before the event is to either use [versions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.versions.aspx) (if the list has them) or use the [ItemUpdating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventreceiver.itemupdating.aspx) event instead.

See [Working with BeforeProperties and AfterProperties on SPItemEventReceiver](http://www.synergyonline.com/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=122) for tables outlining the contents of Event Receivers properties for different events and list types.